# three js camera helper not moving when viewed from secondary 'debug' camera

Tags: three.js

sorry if this post isn't formatted correctly, it's my first.

I'm currently trying to get a CameraHelper to move along a BezierCurve, the camera moves fine, and the camera helper seems to move fine, yet when the scene is viewed from a secondary 'debug' camera, the helper isn't 'moving'.

The helpers position on the debug cam does update when I toggle to the normal camera and back, just not when viewed from the debug cam for the duration of the movement.

I've included cameraHelper.update() in the render loop

```
if (this.animationView) {
        this._effectComposer.render();
    } else {
        this._renderer.render(this._scene, this._debugCamera);
    }

    this._cameraHelper.update();
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure it's something small

Comment: I've found something that helped it to work, still unsure if it's appropriate or not.

invoking updateMatrixWorld() on the camera the helper's attached to seems to work.

`this._camera.updateMatrixWorld(true);`

Comment: Is your camera attached to the scene, if not, there is nothing that would trigger the `updateMatrixWorld` call. In which case it's perfectly reasonable to want to manage that update yourself.

Comment: This should be the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cameraHelper camera (_debugCamera) is added to the scene. I noticed that cameraHelper will render once but it won't update unless it has been added to the scene, even if you call update().

Answer (score -2):

The premise of using ‘CameraHelper’ is to use at least two cameras, so that ‘CameraHelper’ will appear completely on the screen.

```js
// 屏幕相机
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.01, 300)
camera.position.set(-1, 1.2, 1.5)
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)

// 带相机助手的相机
const camera1 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.01, 3)
camera1.position.set(-1, 1.2, 1.5)
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)
let cameraHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper(camera1)
scene.add(cameraHelper)

// 需要每帧更新旋转矩阵
stage.onUpdate(() => {
  cameraHelper.update()
  camera1.updateMatrix()
  camera1.lookAt(0, 0, 0)
})
```

[CameraHelper like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSJC5.png)

Comment: Please refrain from using non english characters. The Stackoverflow.com community is meant to be in English to reach all audiences. Otherwise it is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @ibarrond the notion that a site is "in English to reach all audiences" is a bit absurd. It's in English because the folks who started the site speak English, and the rule excludes anyone who doesn't speak English. It is a necessary evil unfortunately, but don't dress it up as inclusion when it's clearly the opposite.